# Decrypting From OpenSSL PHP Library Using Python

Tags: python, php, encryption, rsa, offline

I'm implementing an RSA encryption scheme where the MySQL database data is encrypted using a public key, and only the private key can be used to decrypt it.

I've managed to do encryption and decryption using the PHP openssl library, and even added a passphrase to protect the private key.

```
// $sRawText is the text string to encrypt.
// $sPublicKey is the public key stored on the server.
openssl_public_encrypt($sRawText, $sResult, $sPublicKey, OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);
// $sResult is the encrypted result which can then be stored in the database.
```

It works great for all the purposes I need to be publicly available, which is to add new entries if a user signs up or, in the future, verify details if they log in. This is sensitive data like contact information, which I only ever use very occasionally. Data that's verify only like passwords can be hashed still, and anything that needs to be read doesn't get encrypted.

Here's how I'm presently decrypting with PHP:

```
// $sPrivateKey is the matching private key.
// $sPassPhrase is the pass phrase (required to decrypt the result).
// $sRawBytes is the encrypted data from the database to decrypt.
$kRsaKey = openssl_pkey_get_private($sPrivateKey, $sPassPhrase);
openssl_private_decrypt($sRawBytes, $sResult, $kRsaKey, OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);
// $sResult will be the decrypted data.
```

The problem with this decryption approach is that it's all taking place live on the server. Obviously, storing the private key on that server would defeat most of the security benefits, as anyone with enough access to the server could pretty easily take it. The best I can come up with using PHP on the server is to pass the private key and/or pass phrase at each time of decryption. However, that still has the key being live there, and also opens up a new attack avenue for the key and pass phrase to be intercepted in those requests.

What I'm trying to do is perform all the decryption offline. So an offline software will be provided the encrypted data in a text file, which it translates into a list of instructions based on the data and intended operation. The private key never leaves that isolated environment and the pass phrase is never stored between sessions.

I'm running into all kinds of hurdles setting up an offline PHP environment, so I thought it might be easier to try to do the decryption in Python. Everything should be standard, or so I thought.

I'm currently trying to use the Python RSA library here:
https://stuvel.eu/python-rsa-doc/reference.html#exceptions

The thing I can't figure out is how to decrypt using the passphrase-protected private key. Would anyone be able to post a really simple example, or is it fundamentally not compatible without major modifications to the Python RSA library? What's the easiest approach to be able to do this decryption offline?

Comment: I would recommend you take a look at another library, mainly Cryptography: https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/
It is a well tested and mature package with a solid team and no problems with passphrase protected keys.

Comment: Thanks vaizki. At the moment that library is working well and I got the key loaded. Both private and public are matching exactly to PHP. When I encrypt text in Python I get an answer which can be decrypted successfully in Python. However, that encrypted value is different than the encrypted value from PHP, and the encrypted value from PHP will fail to decrypt if I try it in Python. What parameters do I want to be looking at to troubleshoot the difference?

Comment: Figured it out. It's using SHA1 instead of SHA256.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I'll post the answer now that I figured out.

(1) We need to get the cryptography library in Python.

On Windows, enter into the command prompt (not Python interpreter):

```
py -m pip install cryptography
```

If the above doesn't work, try replacing 'py' with 'python'.

(2) The private key needs to be in a text file "privatekey.txt".

(3) Use this code for decryption:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding

#privatekey.txt must contain the private key.
#passphrase_bytes must be the passphrase, and it needs to be in bytes (ie b'My Pass Phrase')

with open("privatekey.txt", "rb") as key_file:
private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
    key_file.read(),
    password=passphrase_bytes,
)

#rawtext_bytes must have the bytes of the ciphertext to decrypt
plaintext = private_key.decrypt(
    rawtext_bytes,
    padding.OAEP(
        mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA1()),
        algorithm=hashes.SHA1(),
        label=None
    )
)
#plaintext will now contain the result
```